# Shorthand to declare boolean

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Looking for a way to declare a boolean, something like this:

```
HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=$("home" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}")    // boolean
USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=$("Users" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}")   // boolean
```

except of course the above doesn't work, I get an error:

> bash cannot find home command
>
> bash cannot find Users command

the long way to do this would be:

```
HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=false;
USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=false;

if [ "home" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}" ]; then
  HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=true;
else if [  "Users" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}" ]; then
  USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=true;
fi
```

is there a shorthand for this?

Answer (score 4):

A more compact representation can be achieved with something like the following

```
#!/bin/sh         
BASE_DIRECTORY="home";
[ "home" = "$BASE_DIRECTORY" ] && HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=true || HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=false;
echo $HOME_IS_BASE_DIR;
```

Comment: @alexander-mills your edit is correct. I just provided a more general example :)

Comment: thanks, I like specific examples, it's more clear to the reader :)

Comment: Your second edit was confusing IMHO. It wouldn't even run at all if you didn't define $FOO :)

Answer (score 1):

```
case ${BASE_DIRECTORY} in
    "home")
        HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=true
        USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=false
        ;;
    "Users")
        HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=false
        USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=true
        ;;
    *)
        # Handle heretofore unhandled values here
        ;;
esac
```

It's not exactly shorthand, but it's a both very clear what you're doing, and easy to extend to other locations.  Rather than using those extra variables, though, why not just look at ${BASE_DIRECTORY} directly?

Comment: thanks, the reason I don't want to look at $BASE_DIRECTORY directly is because I wanted to use shorthand later in some other functionality

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for something similar to this:

```bash
HOME_IS_BASE_DIR=$("home" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}")
USERS_IS_BASE_DIR=$("Users" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}")
```

You can make the tests into functions:

```bash
HOME_IS_BASE_DIR()  { [[ "home"  == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}" ]]; }
USERS_IS_BASE_DIR() { [[ "Users" == "${BASE_DIRECTORY}" ]]; }
```

Then you can do tests like this:

```bash
BASE_DIRECTORY="/"

if HOME_IS_BASE_DIR        ; then echo "home is base dir"    ; fi
if ! HOME_IS_BASE_DIR      ; then echo "home is NOT base dir"; fi

if ! HOME_IS_BASE_DIR && \
   ! USERS_IS_BASE_DIR     ; then echo "neither is base dir" ; fi

# output of above:
# home is NOT base dir
# neither is base dir

# ...or use &&/|| instead of 'if':
BASE_DIRECTORY="Users"
USERS_IS_BASE_DIR && echo "Users is base dir"
HOME_IS_BASE_DIR  || echo "home is NOT base dir"

# output of above:
# Users is base dir
# home is NOT base dir
```

The above works for bash and zsh, and can easily be adapted for dash/POSIX.

**Explanation**

In shell scripts, boolean expressions are usually written for exit codes (`cmd1 && cmdd`) etc. The two functions will generate exit codes corresponding to the tests in `[[ .. ]]`, and therefore we can form boolean expressions on the functions.

Remember that the functions are evaluated each time the test is done, so if `BASE_DIRECTORY` is changed, so will the outcome of any tests with `HOME_IS_BASE_DIR` and `USERS_IS_BASE_DIR`.

Comment: Or a bit more flexible: `is_base () { [ "$1" = "$BASE_DIRECTORY" ]; }`, and then later `if is_base Users; then ...; fi` etc., or just `is_base home && echo 'home is base'`.  But what I think this question is _really_ about is whether the script is running on Linux (home directories under `/home`) or macOS (home directories under `/Users`).

Comment: @Kusalananda yep, that's also a possible way to do it.